# jQuery core each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am exploring jQuery framework from its first version. When exploring jquery's code i saw each function twice.

**each** function here is append to jQuery prototype.

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
.......
each: function( fn, args ) {
    return jQuery.each( this, fn, args );
},
```

Abowe the function inside **each** method function returns again Jquery's each method which is derived from extend method.

```
return jQuery.each( this, fn, args );
```

The second function that **each** method returns is below.

```
jQuery.extend({

each: function( obj, fn, args ) {
    if ( obj.length == undefined )
        for ( var i in obj )
            fn.apply( obj[i], args || [i, obj[i]] );
    else
        for ( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ )
            fn.apply( obj[i], args || [i, obj[i]] );
    return obj;
},
```

I would like to know what is purpose to return another each method which is derived via **jquery.extend** method. Can't we use one **each** method directly appended jQuery prototype? Thanks all who have attended.

Comment: Why on earth are you looking at jQuery's core functions!?

Comment: Why would a mechanic ever open the hood of a car?

Comment: You can learn a lot by studying other people's code.

Comment: That is true. My aim is learn what happens behind the scenes one of the most popular javascript framework

Answer (score 4):

It just adds one more way of writing the code, so..

```
$(".elements").each(function(){
  $(this).show();
})
```

..is actually

```
$.each($(".elements"), function(){
  $(this).show();
})
```

Comment: No that is not true, because here is not intented to add another way of calling each method. So I tested as you said, but it throws an error. These are my tests. $.each($('p')).show() or  $("p").each().show();

Comment: That is not what wanted to know. I want to know why author didn't write like this. jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
.......
each: function( obj, fn, args ) {
    if ( obj.length == undefined )
        for ( var i in obj )
            fn.apply( obj[i], args || [i, obj[i]] );
    else
        for ( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ )
            fn.apply( obj[i], args || [i, obj[i]] );
    return obj;
},

Comment: Let's say that you already wrote a function that does that. Wouldn't you use it?

Comment: Of course I can write chainable methods. But  the problem is that what does think Jonh Reizig when writing this each method so? I want to understand logic